# Python&VK_API - Добавление изображения к сообщению

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

У меня есть бот, который отправляет некоторые данные о другом пользователе, и к сообщению которое он отправляет, нужно прикрепить картинку, которой нету на серверах ВК. То есть она хранится на жестком диске, можно ли как то это реализовать?

Comment: Нужно отправить картинку на сервера вк и после отправить сообщение с ее идентификатором, что получили после отправки на сервера: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7d5fa138937358160d6473e614d65b8d301468bc/vk_api__examples/send_images/main.py#L39

Comment: Какой токен используете?

Comment: @nomnoms12 использую токен от группы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы добавить изображение к сообщению Вы должны:

1. ***Загрузить изображение на сервер ВК***

   Для этого можно использовать класс [`VkUpload`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload) и его метод [`photo_messages`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload.photo_messages).
2. ***Сформировать `attachment`***

   Метод `photo_messages` вернёт ответ, в котором будет `owner_id`, `id` и `access_key`. `attachment` формируется следующим образом:

   ```py
   '{type}{owner_id}_{id}_{access_key}'`
   ```

   Для фото `type = 'photo'`.
3. ***Приложить `attachment` к сообщению***

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.upload import VkUpload
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

# Подставьте свои данные!
FILE = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
PEER_ID = 


def main():
    vk_session = VkApi(token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    upload = VkUpload(vk)

    photo_obj = upload.photo_messages(FILE)[0]
    attachment = 'photo{owner_id}_{id}_{access_key}'.format(**photo_obj)

    vk.messages.send(
        random_id=get_random_id(),
        peer_id=PEER_ID,
        attachment=attachment,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```